# Not able to run UFT test using Parallel Runner but same script is working when executed through UFT

Tags: parallel-processing, automation, hp-uft, uft14, microfocus

I am trying to run UFT scripts in parallel using ParallelRunner. Currently I am trying to run one script in UFT and ParallelRunner. My Script is working fine while I am executing it from UFT but when I am using Parallel Runner, it is launching the browser but not validating any steps further.

I have used descriptive programming and not sure because of that it is not working in ParallelRunner. Any help or guidance will be helpful.

Thanks!